# Any way to distinguish between Heroku's scheduled dyno restarts and a new build?

Tags: heroku, cloudflare

I have some code in my app that purges our cache (using Cloudflare's API) every time it starts up so that whenever a change to the website is deployed it shows up instantly for everyone instead of the old version remaining in Cloudflare's cache indefinitely.

Heroku restarts my dyno every 24 hours. This purges Cloudflare for no reason, causes a large spike in traffic, and messes with analytics.

Is there a way to detect on startup if this app restart is occurring due to an actual Heroku deploy, or just due to their daily restart?

One way I've considered is using GitHub's public API to check on startup if a commit has been pushed to master in the last hour, but that seems like a hack and there is probably a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave my app access (via environment variables) to my own Heroku API. This allows it to query the API, asking when its own most recent release was. If the most recent release was more than 24 hours ago, we do not purge Cloudflare. Code is here https://github.com/ImpactDevelopment/ImpactServer/commit/db1cced1ed298b933cee87457eaa844f60974f60#diff-12a774f9437b88d4b4ebbd4e2ab726abR25

This detects anything that causes the app to be rereleased, including code changes, env variable changes, add-on changes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic use case for a [release phase task](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase) (bold mine):

> Release phase enables you to run certain tasks before a new [release](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases) of your app is deployed. Release phase can be useful for tasks such as:
>
> - Sending CSS, JS, and other assets from your app’s slug to a CDN or S3 bucket
> - **Priming or invalidating cache stores**
> - Running database schema migrations
>
> If a release phase task fails, the new release is *not* deployed, leaving your current release unaffected.

Move your "clear cache" logic to a separate script and add it to your `Procfile`, e.g.:

```
web: python some_main_command.py
release: python clear_cache.py
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, my issue with this is that it runs after the build, but **before** the app is back up and running with the new code. So it's too early, the cache is cleared but there's some amount of time (seconds or minutes) while the old files are being served and cached...

Is there a way to run a task after the release is completed? I don't see any =(

Comment: Not as a release task, and I really do think that's the right approach. If you're worried about that you could also warm up your cache in your script.

Comment: What does "warming up" the cache mean? Cloudflare is going 24/7, and as soon as I purge the cache, requests come in immediately (I get about 1.5 requests per second avg). If I purge it then, Cloudflare will refetch the old content immediately (I've seen it). I know because I used to purge as a git commit hook.

Comment: Never mind, it looks like I misunderstood how that works in general and also specifically with CloudFlare.